# Problema al colocar mi pagina online

Tags: php, mysql, servidor, hosting

estoy subiendo una pagina que desarrolle en php con mysql localmente al servidor.

Luego de subir la pagina y crear la base de datos en el servidor cuando voy a la pagina tengo el siguiente problema:

Aunque conecta bien a la base de datos (me permite hacer login con mi usuario el cual esta en la base) el los casos que tengo que listar información de la base de datos no aparece nada.

Fui haciendo var_dumps en el código al hacer las consultas y estas estan vacias, pero mysql no da error alguno.

Se que la consulta es muy abstracta pero estoy un poco perdido en cuanto a cual sea la razón. Agradezco sugerencias

Comment: Ten en cuenta que si el servidor de DB que tienes localmente es diferente al que esta remoto, eso puede causar problemas. Por otro lado, cuando creaste la base de datos, ¿cargaste toda la información que tienes local? ¿Es posible que tu DB remota no tenga información y que por esto no la recibes? Si este no es el problema, considera darnos más información a fin de brindarte una mejor ayuda.

Comment: Hice la importación de las tablas y verifiqué que estuviera correcta. El motor es mysql en ambos, y utilizó phpmyadmin para las modificaciones

Comment: Dices que no recibes errores, pero puede ser que sí los tengas. ¿Probaste con la función [correspondiente para verificar que no hay errores](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php)?

Comment: Los datos que estas mostrando tienen que ver con el usuario logueado? puede haber un problema por ahi?

Comment: @Roxgüel si verifique con mysql error como dices tu. Y no devuelve nada.

Comment: EL servidor es un vps? si no es asi te recomiendo trabajes con algun servicio externo de almacenamiento de datos, como puede ser firebase, saludos.

Comment: @gbianchi me pasan con datos que no dependen del usuario y con datos que si. Tengo una tabla con nombres de eventos y tendría que listarlos pero no lo hace. En la base están.

Comment: Si no los lista, tiene que haber un error por algun lado. tenes controles de error en tu codigo?

Comment: No hay error porque devuelve vacío como si no hubiera datos en la tabla. Pero si están los datos y la consulta está correcta porque al probarla en phpmyadmin funciona

Comment: Se me ocurre que tienes una diferencia con tu servidor PHP local y remoto. Quizá alguna configuración del `php.ini`. ¿Dices que al escribir la consulta en PhpMyAdmin devuelve los resultados que esperas? Entonces se me ocurre que hay un problema al momento de procesarlos. Intentaría comparar los `phpinfo()` remoto y local. Y también me inclino por probar en un archivo externo, una consulta básica como `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Usuarios` y ver qué resultado te arroja

Comment: Voy a probar y cuento cómo me fue

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar el problema con dos cambios:

1- Cambie la version de php a 7.3 en cPanel. Por defecto tenía la 5 pero yo utilizaba la 7 para desarrollar el programa localmente.

2- En las opciones de configuración de las propiedades de php en cPanel faltaba marcar la característica nd_mysqli. Por esto algunas clases de mysqli no estaban cargadas en el servidor y eso hacia que algunas consultas devolvieran datos vacíos.

Muchas gracias a todos por los comentarios